# JavaScript - React JS

Tags: rest, restful, react

Como eu faço para pegar uma parte de um JSON, colocar numa variavel e depois jogar essa variavel num "Widget" do meu layout?

Exemplo: (http://ip.jsontest.com/) quero pegar o valor de "ip", e colocar no meu widget no lugar do valor '1,410'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      data:[]
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
        let URL = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'
           fetch(URL)
           .then(function(response) {
              let data = response.json()
              return data;
           })
           .then((json) => {
              console.log('parsed json', json)
              data : json;
           })
  }
 render(){
 return(
  <div className="container text-center">
      <div className="row">
      <h1> Quero que apareca o Ip aqui = {this.state.data.ip}</h1>
```

Comment: Em vez de somente `data : json;` tens de usar `this.setState({data : json});` já testaste isso?

Comment: Funcionou com isso que me passaste, Muito Obrigado ! :D

Comment: Henrique: usa `this.state = {
    data: {}
  }`, com um objeto para ser mais correto, visto que será um objeto no futuro quando o json chegar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens de usar o `setState`, é isso que na API do React faz chamar o render de novo.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: {}
  }
}
componentDidMount(){
        let URL = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'
        fetch(URL).then(response => this.setState({data: response.json()});

}
render(){
    return(
      <div className="container text-center">
          <div className="row">
          <h1>{this.state.data.ip}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia já usar chamadas asincronas para sua aplicação usando async/await
e també um try/catch para tratar o success e o error da chamada.

exemplo:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: {}
  }
}
async componentDidMount(){
  let URL = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'

  try{
    const response = await fetch(URL)
    this.setState({data: response.json()})
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err.response)
  }
}
render(){
    return(
      <div className="container text-center">
          <div className="row">
          <h1>{this.state.data.ip}</h1>
```